# How can I show the the build version and if its running on 64 or 32 bits in my program?

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit

How can I show in my program if its running on 64 or 32 bit?  (i.e. If i compiled it on 64 or 32 bit)

Also how can I show the build version?

Thanks

Comment: And it would probably be better to break this into two questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the version:

```
 var ver = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

(where `Program` can be replaced with any type from the assembly you are interested in)

For the architecture:

```
bool x64 = IntPtr.Size == 8;
```

If you want the ClickOnce deployment version, that is obtainable - but separately (and needs a reference to `System.Deployment.dll`):

```
if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    var ver = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment
           .CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, how to increase the FileVersion or the Version Automatic ?

Comment: @Gali - by file version - you mean that windows sees? I use a fixup in my build script to set the assembly version and assembly file version attributes - something similar may help

Comment: can i get any sample for this fixup ?

Answer (score 2):

For 32/64 bit:

```
bool x64;
unsafe { x64 = sizeof(System.IntPtr) == 8; }
if (x64)
    Console.WriteLine("64 bits");
else
    Console.WriteLine("32 bits");
```

Your build numbers can be incremented in your project's `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

And this snippet to get your assembly's version at runtime:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileVersion);
```

Comment: Apparently you can use `IntPtr.Size` which doesn't need `unsafe`, although I've not tested this myself as I don't have a x64 OS installed.

Comment: I whipped that up in Snippet Compiler running against .NET 3.5. Got a compiler error without the unsafe and had to also set the app properties to allow unsafe blocks. Too lazy to mess with VS tonight. ;-)

Comment: thanks for the help, how to increase the FileVersion or the Version Automatic ?

Comment: Doesn't this say what version you are running on? I thought he wanted to know what version it was compiled on. Looking at his question again he actually asks both.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this microsoft documentation it gives you more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.build.aspx

System.Version.Build has properties that give you all the build numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting .Net 4.0 you can use [Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx) and [Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx).